# Boto3 to pull data from Public S3 Bucket, into my S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a python script that works perfectly on my local computer. I want to migrate this script to Lambda, and run it in AWS Cloud.

The Local script uses Boto3 to pull a geopackage file from a public AWS S3 Bucket(noaa-ocs-nationalbathymetry-pds). It then saves the geopackage to my local PC, and converts it to a shapefile.

I want the Lambda Script to pull the geopackage file from the S3 Bucket(noaa-ocs-nationalbathymetry-pds), and upload the geopackage to my own S3 bucket(geopackageshapefile). (I removed the shapefile conversion, because the Python runtime in my free tier, did not support arcpy).

[Original Script (Works on local):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11z5T.png)

[Lambda modified script]

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
from botocore import UNSIGNED
import os

def download(event, context):
    # Create AWS credentials even though S3 is public
    cred = {"aws_access_key_id": "", 
            "aws_secret_access_key": "", 
            "config": Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED)}
    
    # Create session
    session = boto3.Session()
    client = session.client('s3', **cred)
    
    # Define source S3 bucket and object key/prefix
    source_bucket = 'noaa-ocs-nationalbathymetry-pds'
    prefix = 'BlueTopo/_BlueTopo_Tile_Scheme/BlueTopo_Tile_Scheme'
    
    # Use paginator to iterate through objects
    paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    objs = paginator.paginate(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=prefix).build_full_result()
    
    if len(objs['Contents']) == 0:
        print(f"No geometry found in {prefix}")
        return
    
    # Source name variable. 
    source_name = objs['Contents'][0]['Key']
    
    # Define destination S3 bucket and key
    destination_bucket = 'geopackageshapefile'
    destination_key = 'Lambda_Out/Output.gpkg' 
    
    # Download object from source bucket to a temporary file
    temp_file = '/tmp/Output.gpkg'  # AWS Lambda provides limited storage in /tmp
    client.download_file(source_bucket, source_name, temp_file)
    
    # Upload the temporary file to the destination bucket
    client.upload_file(temp_file, destination_bucket, destination_key)
    
    # Remove the temporary file
    os.remove(temp_file)

    print(f"Geopackage downloaded from {source_bucket}/{source_name} and uploaded to {destination_bucket}/{destination_key}")
```

[Errors being received in AWS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rly1n.png)

Some things to note that I have already changed:

Lambda Timeout: Extended to 2.5 minutes (Fails after 4 sec.)

Lambda Execution Roles: Set up in IAM
[Lambda Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xabz.png)

S3 Bucket policy:

````
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::874692768816:role/LambdaDownload"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::geopackageshapefile/*"
        }
    ]
}```

AmazonS3FullAccess Policy JSON (IAM Role attached to Lambda Function)
```{
   
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}```

AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole Policy JSON (IAM Role attached to Lambda Function)

```{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}```



FYI, I am fairly new to AWS. I know there are easier ways to get data from one bucket into the other, but I really wanted to try a code migration to Lambda, and thought this would be a good opportunity to try that. 

Thanks in advance, really appreciate any help.  





Timeout: Thought the timeout limit was being exceeded so I increased the limit.

Access Policy: Attached a new IAM Role with the appropriate permissions, rather than the default exe role. 

Bucket S3 policy: Added policy to the S3 bucket for access.
````

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Also, you mentioned you attached an IAM role (I assume this is attached to the Lambda function) and you created an S3 bucket policy, but something isn't working, so how can you be sure those policies are correct? Please edit your question to show the details of those policies.

Comment: If the IAM role has S3 permissions as shown then the S3 bucket policy is not required, assuming the bucket is in the same account as the IAM role.

Comment: I added the S3 Access Policy and the Lambda Execution policy JSONs. These are both part of the IAM Role being assumed by the Lambda function. Also, understood the S3 bucket policy isn't needed.. But the errors are being introduce with and without the bucket policy

Comment: You seem to be using the same S3 client for both the unauthenticated download and for the authentication-required upload. It has the same set of (anonymous) credentials in both cases, no?

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying. So the same anonymous Boto client which retrieves the data, is trying to upload it, which is why its getting denied.. No necessary credentials on the boto client when uploading. Still doing some reading, but it looks like I may need to use an s3.boto client, or something like s3.meta.client.. Still reading some things on it, but def may be causing the issue. Thanks

Comment: After you do the download, just do something like `client = session.client('s3')` to create an S3 client with the credentials pulled from the Lambda environment to perform the upload.

Comment: Excellent! it worked. I added                       ```s3_client.download_file(source_bucket, source_name, temp_file)
    
    # Create a new S3 client for upload
    s3_upload_client = session.client('s3')
    
    # Upload the temporary file to the destination bucket
    s3_upload_client.upload_file(temp_file, destination_bucket, destination_key) ```                                     A little confused on how the S3 client auto pulls from the Lambda Env. Thanks so much

Comment: Also created the new session at the beginning of the code ```# Create session
    session = boto3.Session()
    s3_client = session.client('s3', **cred)```

Comment: You are welcome to add your own Answer to assist future readers!

Comment: If you are going to perform this operation on _many_ files, you might consider using a Copy operation instead of a Download+Upload. A Copy API call can copy objects between S3 buckets without the need to download first. I wouldn't suggest changing your code if you just need the one object, but using Copy is useful if you have hundreds of objects to copy.